# Distinguishability in Probability theory

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory

Reading Sheldon and Ross Introduction to Probability Theory. I'm on section 1.6.

They say that there are $r^{n}$ possible outcomes when n distinguishable balls are to be distributed among r distinguishable urns. This makes sense to me.

Then they say that the answer is different when the $n$ balls are indistinguishable. I take it indistinguishable means that the balls(for all intents or purposes) are representing the same exact object. Then they say that it is a vector ($x_1$,$x_2$,...,$x_r$).

I don't understand what's happening in this case. How is the answer different if the balls are exactly the same?

Comment: Take $2$ distinguishable kids (urns), and $2$ indistinguishable candies (balls). The possible patterns are $(0,2)$, $(1,1)$, and $(2,0)$, so $3$ patterns. In the case of distinguishable balls, you saw that the number of ways is $2^2$.

Comment: Thank you so much. The candle analogy works so much better then urns and balls!

Comment: You are welcome. Yes, kids and candies are concrete. Note that with $n$ distinguishable candies, and $2$ kids, there are $2^n$ ways to distribute, while with indistinguishable candies there are only $n+1$. There is a good Wikipedia article you may want to look at, Stars and Bars (combinatorics).

Comment: We are assuming that the kids are lined up in a line and stay in the same position all the time, i.e. the first kid is ALWAYS the first kid, second kid the second... etc, right? That the only possibilities are how the candles being distributed into the kids?

Comment: I ask because the summary only says that the balls(candles)  are indistinguishable, not so much the urns(kids) If this is the case, then this question makes complete sense to me.

Comment: Yes. An unrealistic assumption about kids. Maybe we could line up the urns, and put each kid in an urn. Kidding aside, it is often useful to imagine that objects are lined up in some fixed order irrelevant to the calculation, such as age or student number.

Comment: There are two more classes of problems possible here, distinguishable balls and indistinguishable urns, and both indistinguishable. Both are harder, particularly the second. For a general discussion, with references, please see Wikipedia, *The Twelvefold Way*.

Comment: hahaha! Yes indeed! Thanks for all the help and useful wikipedia entries! They helped a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Lets assume that we line up r distinguishable urns in a line. Urn A, Urn B, ... Urn R.

The question starts off by saying that there are $r^n$ different ways to distribute n distinguishable balls into r distinguishable urns. Because each urn can hold more than one ball, each ball has r different places it could end up, thus $r^n$

Now, lets suppose that the balls are indistinguishable (i.e. for all intents and purposes the balls are exactly the same). This would mean that when we distribute 4 balls into 3 urns, that if we put 1 ball in urn A 1 ball in Urn B and 2 balls in urn C, we count this only one time.(It doesn't matter on which distribution the ball ended up in urn A, a ball in urn A and a ball in urn B is counted only once. This is opposed to distinguishable balls and urns)

This turns the problem more into a vector problem. Now the goal is to the find the distinct vectors $(x_1,x_2,...,x_r)$ = $n$.

Thus the number of solutions to this problem is almost clear. It basically says how many different ways can you create r groups from these n indistinguishable objects. The book uses a clever answer which uses combinations to find the answer.

0 | 0 |... | 0 | 0

Let all the 0 be the balls. The question than becomes, how many different ways can you separate these balls. There are n-1C r-1 (because if you are creating 3 urns you need to separators. This thus gives us that there are that many positive distinct solutions to the the equation $x_1 + x_2 + ... + x_r = n$.